# Is there anyway to freeze or lock the DOM of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there anyway to freeze or lock the DOM of a page, so no further changes (CSS or Javascript etc) can be made to it?

I keep having difficulty in finding elements that appear or disappear when the `div` or page loses focus.

My normal approach of right clicking an element to inspect it makes the element disappear from the DOM.

By manually searching through the DOM Inspector, I can find the element, but as soon as I click on it inside the Inspector the element disappears from the DOM.

This whole situation results in certain interactive parts of the page being complete unreachable. I cannot find out what CSS rules are applied to them, what line number in which CSS file I should look or anything. And I really dont want to have to search through multiple CSS files, looking at each rule and trying to figure out if this is the rule I am looking for.

Comment: do you want to just inspect your element?then use undock into separate window.in chrome

Comment: Can you just open the developer tool and use the little mouse icon to search for the inspectable element? This way you wont have to click on them.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the options in `Break on...` in the context menu for elements in the DOM? (In Chrome) e.g. `Break on Node removal`

Comment: You can also set element's state in css with :hover, :focus, etc in the developer console.

Comment: @thepio The particular element I am trying to get at disappears when I click on anything in the inspector window - then I cant find it

Comment: @epascarello This element is set as a :after element, it is created with Javascript - the element is set :after a div with about 20 classes applied to it....

Comment: @sdgluck That sounds useful - can you add that as an answer and expand on it slightly? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using one of the options in `Break on...` in the context menu for DOM elements in the Chrome Developer Console?

For example, `Break on Node removal`. This will act as a breakpoint for removal of a particular DOM element.

[image]

(click the image to see it larger)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to break AFTER the node has been removed.  I am correct in selecting the parent node yeah?

Comment: @Jimmery It should break before... see [this example](https://i.imgur.com/MhSRX0m.gif).

Answer (score 0):

If the styles are applied when an element is in a state such as hovered/focused, you can force the element state in chrome.

1. Inspect the element you want to have the state.
2. Click the `:hov` menu option in the styles panel
3. Click the checkbox that is the state you want

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools]

Or

1. Right click on the element's tag in the Element pane
2. Select the CSS state from the context menu

[image: context menu]

Other browsers have similar options.

Comment: As I stated in the comments - This element is set as a :after element, it is created with Javascript (not because of :hover or :active etc) - so none of this is helpful to me...